# Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_get()

Tags: php, cross-domain

I tried to make cross domain request in php coding using http_get.  In my server, there is no required modules installed.  I dont know what to install to make posible of doing http_get.

The error which i got was

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_get() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\article\index.php on line 2

I tried to do so (PECL pecl_http >= 0.1.0)
http_get — Perform GET request

but, i did not find out solution.

So, please help me to run http_get coding.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you have to enable `extension=php_http.dll` in your `php.ini` file and after that restart your Apache Server.
I advise you to use **cURL** instead of `http_get()` (same manipulation, you have to enable `extension=php_curl.dll` and restart apache)

Hope that Helps :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you advise them to use cURL instead?

Comment: @Halayem Can you give a usage example for cURL?  `http_get()` is still undefined.

Answer (score 3):

To directly answer the question, you've to enable `extension=php_http.dll` in  `php.ini` and restart apache, but there's absolutely no need to use `http_get()` in our days.

Here's 3 good alternatives:

1. The php [curl](http://codular.com/curl-with-php) library
2. [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
3. [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

---

`Curl` usage:

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://testcURL.com/?item1=value&item2=value2',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'User Agent X'
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

---

`file_get_content()`  usage:

```
$my_var = file_get_contents("https://site/");
```

---

`copy()`  usage:

```
copy("https://site/image.png", "/local/image.png");
```